# Insert data into table except one column SQL

Tags: sql

I just want to know if it is possible to insert data into a table that has columns for example `ID, FIRST_NAME, AGE, SEX, SALARY` but I want to insert into all columns except the column `id`.

Normally as I know I need to set this code

```
INSERT_INTO TABLE_NAME (FIRST_NAME, AGE, SEX, SALARY) 
VALUES (....);
```

but it will take a long time if there is a lot of columns...

Is there any code that will grant me time?

Comment: Why would it take a long time to `INSERT`? Do you have lots on indexes on your table that's showing down the speed on your DML statements?

Comment: @Larnu: I believe he's referring to the **typing** of the query  .... too many columns to type out to just skip one ....

Comment: No, there is no "magic trick" to get around this - if you have 200 columns, and want to insert into 199 of those - you'll have to spell out those 199 columns explicitly. That's just the way SQL is. But as @larnu mentions - there are **tools** that can help you with that - maybe not free to use, but if you're a professional programmer, well worth their money!

Comment: Perhaps. If so, this is when a good extension to help you autocomplete the statement is useful.

Comment: okay thanks for the info, I'm just a beginner tho

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can pass null value for the columns you don't want to set.

Entry will be inserted with the default value if provided in the schema, or null is field is nullable

Comment: 0


the thing is I have auto_increment in the ID value if I did null on the value will it still do the auto_increment command?

Comment: null and  '' are values that will be set too.

Comment: @DonFleym for this specific column yes, indeed, it will

Comment: Okay thanks guys for the help